# Difference between defining a function within document.ready or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between defining a function within document.ready or not ?

Does it affect the scope of when a function can be invoked ?

Example, is there any issues/differences I should be aware of in location definitions of functions inside() & outside() :

```
<script>
document.ready(){
 function inside(){
    alert('inside');
 }
}

 function outside(){
    alert('outside');
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can only access the `inside` function from inside the callback for the `ready` event:

```
document.ready(function(){

  function inside(){
    alert('inside');
  }

  inside(); // works
  outside(); // works

});

function outside(){
  alert('outside');
}

inside(); // doesn't work
outside(); // works
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does it affect the scope of when a function can be invoked ?

Yes, and nothing else.

(Although your particular example depends on you adding a `ready()` method to the `document`object first.)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has function level scoping, meaning if you define a function in document.ready it won't be available outside document.ready

I would define a namespace outside like so: 
    var app = {};

Then define your inside function like so:
    app.inside = function() {

Then inside will be available in your app global namespace.